# Example that two distributions are both dependent and independent

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $X_1,X_2$ be random vectors such that $F_{X_1}=F_{X_2}$. ($F$ denotes CDFs)

Let $Y_1,Y_2$ be random vectors such thar $F_{Y_1}=F_{Y_2}$.

If $X_1,Y_1$ are independent, then are $X_2,Y_2$ necessarily independent? I guess this is obviously false, but since I am new to probability theory, I am not sure how to construct such one. What would be a counterexample?

Comment: $F_1$ and $F_2$ are joint distribution functions of what variable?

Comment: Actually, it need not be specified, because joint distributions can be completely characterized without invoking random vectors. But, here, let’s say $F_1=F_{X_1}$ and $F_2=F_{X_2}$, as given in my post

Comment: I don’t see an issue here, but then I will edit my question with that terminology

Comment: Done :) ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I didn't understand your question first. Now I see it makes sense. I agree with you. You can somehow construct r.v.s such that $F_{X_2}*F_{Y_2} \neq F_{X_2,Y_2}$. Then you can construct your $X_1$ and $Y_1$ with $F_{X_1}=F_{X_2}$ and $F_{Y_1}=F_{Y_2}$according to the distribution $F_{X_1,Y_1}=F_{X_2}*F_{Y_2}$.

Comment: Distributions are not dependent or independent; random variables are. Dependence or independence is determined by the _joint_ distribution, which his determined by the _joint_ c.d.f. $F_{X_1,Y_1}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah, but my point here is that whether the concept “independence” can be completely characterized without invoking the term “random vector”, which I think is not true. So I want to see a counterexample..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributions are not dependent or independent; random variables are. Dependence or independence is determined by the *joint* distribution, which his determined by the *joint* c.d.f. $F_{X_1,Y_1}.$

Consider these probability mass functions
\begin{align}
& \begin{array}{ll} f_{X_1,Y_1}(0,0)= 1/4, & f_{X_1,Y_1}(0,1) = 1/4 \\ f_{X_1,Y_1}(1,0) = 1/4, & f_{X_1,Y_1}(1,1) = 1/4  \end{array} \\[12pt]
\hline
& \begin{array}{ll} f_{X_2,Y_2}(0,0)= 1/2, & f_{X_2,Y_2}(0,1) = 0 \\ f_{X_2,Y_2}(1,0) = 0, & f_{X_2,Y_2}(1,1) = 1/2  \end{array}
\end{align}

It follows that $f_{X_1} = f_{X_2}$ and $f_{Y_1} = f_{Y_2},$ but $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are independent but $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are not.

Comment: Why is $f_{X_1}=f_{X_2}$? How do I deduce that? What are $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ here?

Comment: @Rubertos : $$ f_{X_1}(0) = \Pr(X_1=0) = \Pr( (X_1,Y_1)=(0,0) \text{ or } (X_1,Y_1) = (0,1)) = \frac 1 4 + \frac1 4 = \frac 1 2 $$ and  $f_{X_1}(1)$ is found similarly, and also $f_{X_2}. \qquad$